# Differences between MariaDB docker tags

Tags: mariadb, installation, docker

I need to install MariaDB 10.5 latest GA with docker.

What is the main difference between the following tags?

- 10.5.11-focal
- 10.5-focal
- 10-focal
- focal
- 10.5.11
- 10.5
- 10
- latest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer:  Nothing.

Long answer:

"Latest" refers to be the latest, which is 10.5.y; some day soon it may refer to the latest 10.6.y, which is is early stages of being released.
10 refers to the lastest 10.x.y
10.5 refers to the latest 10.5.y
10.5.11 seems to be the latest available 10.5.y

"Focal" refers to the base OS the Docker container is built on which, in this case, would be Ubuntu 20.04 a.k.a. "Focal Fossa"

Comment: To see what's the different at the latest release, [this is the source](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/blob/master/library/mariadb) in which you can see the equivalence of tags. For more detailed information [repo-info](https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/blob/master/repos/mariadb/remote/) on what is on docker hub is also there.

Comment: There is now a `lts` tag for the latest long term supported version.